# Don't change input file text on non accepted file

Tags: javascript, html, file

I've a code that implements that if the user chooses a file that is not jpg, jpeg or png it displays an error message.

```
async function read(input) {
  var file = input.files[0];
  var idxDot = file.name.lastIndexOf(".") + 1;
  var extFile = file.name.substr(idxDot, file.name.length).toLowerCase();
  if (extFile=="jpg" || extFile=="jpeg" || extFile=="png"){
      fileContent = await readFile(file);
  }else{
      alert("Only jpg, jpeg or png allowed");
  }

}
```

This is called from this:

```
<input type="file" align="center" accept=".jpg,.jpeg,.png" onchange="read(this)"/>
```

Problem is that regardless the file what was taken it changes the text of the file input to the selected file wether it was an accepted type or not. Although fileContent continues to be empty or has the last value for the last selected accpted file, the file shown is another one.

How to avoid this behavior so if an accepted file is the one chosen the text for the choosen file isn't changed?

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent the input file text from changing by just setting the input value to `null` like:

```
async function read(input) {
  var file = input.files[0];
  var idxDot = file.name.lastIndexOf(".") + 1;
  var extFile = file.name.substr(idxDot, file.name.length).toLowerCase();
  if (extFile=="jpg" || extFile=="jpeg" || extFile=="png"){
      fileContent = await readFile(file);
  }else{
      alert("Only jpg, jpeg or png allowed");
      input.value = null;
  }
}
```

DEMO:

```js
async function read(input) {
  var file = input.files[0];
  var idxDot = file.name.lastIndexOf(".") + 1;
  var extFile = file.name.substr(idxDot, file.name.length).toLowerCase();
  if (extFile=="jpg" || extFile=="jpeg" || extFile=="png"){
      //fileContent = await readFile(file);
      alert("Valid file selected!");
  }else{
      alert("Only jpg, jpeg or png allowed");
      input.value = null;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="file" align="center" accept=".jpg,.jpeg,.png" onchange="read(this)"/>
<br/>
<p>Please select a non-image file like a pdf for testing.</p>
```

Comment: thanks but this only partially answers my question, if you first take an accepted file type and then you select and invalid one it leaves input empty instead of keeping the previous valid file. I checked to set previous value of the file but this gives an error.